# Programmatically get Zeppelin context (aka 'z object')

Tags: scala, apache-zeppelin

Let's say I have an external library (written in Scala) that is configured as a dependency for Apache Zeppelin's Spark Interpreter. Such a library needs to access current Zeppelin context (which is, for instance, injected in notebooks as 'the z object`) when called from Zeppelin notebooks. How can this be done?

I'm wondering if there exists something equivalent to Spark context access, which can be gotten or created (`val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()`).

Thanks in advance!